# Regex for date, match this year months plus december of previous year and january of next year

Tags: regex, date

Hello i'm trying to write a regex that would match all the month names in a string by this criterium:

- if string contains just the month name than it's valid
- if the string contains the month name and starts/ends with year, then the year has to be the current year, but it has to also match december of previous year and january of next year

through example:

```
june - valid
june 2014 - valid
2014 june - valid
june 2013 - invalid
june 2015 - invalid

december - valid
december 2013 - valid
december 2015 - invalid

january - valid
january 2015 - valid
january 2013 - invalid
```

i use the following regex:

```
^(?:2014\s*|2015\s*(january)|2014\s*(december)|)(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|)(?:\s*2014|(december)\s*?2013|(january)\s*?2015|)?$
```

but it gives me "" as a result when i try *january 2015*

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "january 2015"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(6) "january"
}
```

or if i try *2015 january*

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "2015 january"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "january"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

so then i have to ignore all the empty values and find the correct one

Can you guys help?

Comment: Perhaps this is bad advice, but I would consider using [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You have not written in which language you want to apply the regular expression.

However, if the regex search string contains multiple marking groups, you will get always also multiple strings returned with most strings being empty.

It is perhaps possible to get the month according to your requirements with a single regular expression, but I don't know how.

My suggestion is as follows:

First, the following regular expression is applied on the string:

```
^(?:2014)?[\t ]*(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)[\t ]*(?:2014)?$
```

The task is accomplished if this regular expression returns a month string.

But if no string is returned, a second regex must be executed on the string:

```
^(?:2015)?[\t ]*(january)[\t ]*(?:2015)?$
```

The task is accomplished if this regular expression returns string `january`.

But if again no string is returned, a third regex must be executed on the string:

```
^(?:2013)?[\t ]*(december)[\t ]*(?:2013)?$
```

The task is accomplished if this regular expression returns string `december`.

Otherwise with all 3 regex searches returning false and therefore no month, the evaluated string does not contain a valid month information.

This solution with up to 3 regex searches will be definitely faster than a solution with a single, very complex regex search string.

Comment: No, I have not done tests as I have no single regex search string which I could use for comparison. But after years of experience on searching especially on very large files I know that first running a simple regex search and if really necessary 1 or 2 more also simple regex searches is faster than running a very complex single regex search which requires internally lots of forward and backward positioning in the searched string by the regex engine.

Comment: Hi i've tested your answer and i've got the following results

I've run the test 10x, usign 6 different string

My execution time: 0.00076436996459961
Suggested execution time: 0.0011527538299561

Written in PHP

Answer (score 0):

first match year and month by using something like this   ((jan|feb|...) are all month names):

```
/(\d{4})?(jan|feb|...)(\d{4})?/i
```

then if text matched for each case do your validation. (script in php)

```
if($match[1]=="")
  $year=intval($match[3]);
else
  $year=intval($match[1]);
if($year==$currentYear-1){
  //month($match[2]) should be jan or dec
}else if($year==$currentYear){
  //month could be everything
}else{
  //invalid year
}
```